# Is there an update to AuthorizeNet.php with SHA-512 to replace MD5 check?

Tags: civicontribute

Is there an SHA-512 replacement for the AuthorizeNet.php module yet? If not I can work on it

Comment: You might want to follow https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues/39

Answer (score 2):

Lesley, CiviCRM 5.11.0 doesn't use anymore MD5 check on authorize.net. This [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13474) removes the check. However there is still not PR submitted by anyone to support SHA-512 check.

If you can submit a PR to support this would be very useful to the community.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Hi Pradeep I can work on it - it would be a patch that would need to also allow Admin/Process Payment form to input SHA-512 key, not just update AuthorizeNet.php. In the meantime, thank for pointing out the latest pull request.

Comment: I have submitted fixes in the past using Issue Tracker, and I see that now Civicrm is using Gitlab, not JIra, etc.  I 'joined'/registered, but now, do I need to 'request' joining a group? Can I not simply submit this as an issue for review, this is an update, not an extension. Can you send me the url I need to go to 1) submit this change as an issue and 2) git clone the latest release?

Comment: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/core/contributing/